# Fitting data by linear combination of distribution

Tags: fitting, peak-detection

I have data

```
test3={0.329727, 2.58106, 3.13688, 4.75399, 6.64089, 9.73916, 11.7021, 14.4481, 16.3523, 14.6448, 14.1997, 16.8602, 18.1041, 17.6997, 15.804, 13.9181, 12.5242, 10.8824, 8.61049, 4.43998, 2.78258, 0.329727}
```

My aim is to fit this data by linear combination of normal distributions. My graphical image is below.

```
a = Range[22];
b = N[Exp[-(a - 9)^2/8]];
c = N[Exp[-(a - 14)^2/10]];
d = N[Exp[-(a - 18)^2/3]];
g = ListLinePlot[{b*13, c*17, d * 2}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 20}}];
data = ListLinePlot[test3, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}];
Show[{g, data}]
```

I want to find the best parameters by least squares, and also want to get the residuals. I tried the code (Method1 and Method2 below) but unfortunately, they did not work at all.

Method1:

```
ClearAll;
peakfunc[A1_, μ1_, σ1_, xz_] = 
  A1^2 E^(-((xz - μ1)^2/(2 σ1^2)));
ff = FindFit[test3, 
  peakfunc[AA1, uu1, ss1, xi1] + peakfunc[AA2, uu2, ss2, xi1] + 
  peakfunc[AA3, uu3, ss3, xi1],
  {AA, uu, ss, AA2, uu2, ss2, AA3, uu3, ss3}, xi1]
```

Method2:

```
fit2 = LeastSquares[test3, I1 * NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1] +
  I2 * NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2] + 
  I3 * NormalDistribution[μ3, σ3]]
```

Can anyone tell me how to fit data by linear combination of distributions, using least squares? How can I find the residuals?

Comment: You have too many typos in `ff`.  `{AA, uu, ss....` should be `{AA1, uu1, ss1,...`.  Then Method1 works.

Comment: And method2 does not work because `LeastSquares` expects a matrix as firstand a vector as second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

test3 = {0.329727, 2.58106, 3.13688, 4.75399, 6.64089, 9.73916, 11.7021, 
   14.4481, 16.3523, 14.6448, 14.1997, 16.8602, 18.1041, 17.6997, 15.804, 
   13.9181, 12.5242, 10.8824, 8.61049, 4.43998, 2.78258, 0.329727};

b = Exp[-(a - 9)^2/8];
c = Exp[-(a - 14)^2/10];
d = Exp[-(a - 18)^2/3];

model1 = e*b + f*c + g*d;

(nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[test3, model1, {e, f, g}, a]) // Normal

(* 8.60435 E^(-(1/3) (-18 + a)^2) + 16.757 E^(-(1/10) (-14 + a)^2) + 
 15.6088 E^(-(1/8) (-9 + a)^2) *)

nlm1["FitResiduals"]

(* {0.32449, 2.54691, 2.96339, 4.06743, 4.52339, 4.64389, 2.11012, 0.215539, \
-0.631974, -2.51307, -2.08038, 0.560179, 0.82727, 0.215376, 0.0398736, \
0.383335, -0.4592, -1.10575, 1.06965, 1.71403, 2.22941, 0.260343} *)

Show[
 Plot[nlm1[a], {a, 1, Length[test3]}],
 ListPlot[test3, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Using a more general model

```
model2 = Total[a[#]*PDF[NormalDistribution[m[#], s[#]], x] & /@ Range[3]];

(nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[test3, {model2, s[1] > 0, s[2] > 0, s[3] > 0}, 
    Variables[Level[model2, {-2}]], x]) // Normal

(* 17.2599 E^(-0.0343736 (-13.9513 + x)^2) + 
 3.61682 E^(-0.854967 (-8.67433 + x)^2) + 
 7.76263 E^(-0.0704611 (-6.80838 + x)^2) *)

nlm2["FitResiduals"]

(* {-0.444829, 0.931468, 0.0634757, -0.272829, -0.622949, 0.353486, 0.35172, \
-0.135931, 0.0838876, -0.0388931, -0.880784, 0.555403, 0.851822, 0.238308, \
-0.884226, -1.04314, -0.0206329, 1.0562, 1.42361, -0.467585, -0.345967, \
-1.53221} *)

Show[
 Plot[nlm2[x], {x, 1, Length[test3]}],
 ListPlot[test3, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your kind description!! Though I'm on the way to study Mathematica programming, I often struggle to solve problem of my own data, only with Wolfram Help page. Not only I learned how to get fitted data, but also I understand the way to use NormalDistribution command now. I'm really grateful to you.